# Writing network driver for Raspberry Pi GPIO connected to FS1000A

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, gpio

I want to create a Linux network driver for a FS1000A connected to the RasPI via GPIO. It does not need to support a high bitrate.

The hardware is already working, I've previously managed to emulate a [433 MHz remote control](https://github.com/alexbirkett/ever-flourish-remote-control-plug) using a FS1000A transmitter connected to a Raspberry PI's GPIO pins. The FS1000A transmitter and receiver use on off keying. If the GPIO pin is set high, the transmitter transmits a carrier. If it's set low it does not transmit.

According to [an article about writing virtual interfaces](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/vinter/vinter.html),  "A virtual interface has no way to receive interrupts, and thus it cannot receive any network packet." Is it possible to receive an interrupt when a GPIO pin changes state on a Raspberry PI? If not it is possible for a network driver to get a callback to poll the state of a GPIO pin? It does not have to be elegant or efficient, it just needs to work.

Does a network driver's xmit function have to block until all the data is sent? That could take a long time the packet is transmitted 9600 bps.

I read a guide to [writing network device drivers for Linux](http://linuxgazette.net/156/jangir.html) but it is focused on PCI devices. Is there any documentation/tutorials about writing network drivers for Linux?

Any other tips suggestions welcome.

Comment: This is a question about how to write a network driver. I previously used the same hardware to emulate a remote control. I've updated the text to try to make this clearer.

Comment: I want to be able to send ethernet frames over it to another similar RasPi device. So I assumed I needed a network driver. The network driver API appears to be what I'm looking for, it calls you when it wants to send a frame and you call it when you have a frame. What are my other options and why are they better?